# is it possible to add gradient color using one name flutter

Tags: flutter

I want to define below gradient color in one name to use multiple places in my code.is  it posssible in flutter

like this >>  const Color backgroundBlue = Color(0xff0F1A2E);

```
   gradient: LinearGradient(
            colors: [
              Color.fromRGBO(125, 158, 205, 1.0),
              Color.fromRGBO(115, 131, 163, 0.7490196078431373),
            ],
            begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
            end: Alignment.centerRight,
          ),
```

Answer (score 2):

if the focus is to use only one file, you can define at the beginning of the file what to make the calls, but if you intend to use it in multiple files you can create a new file and inside it create a constant with LinearGradient and import where you need

```dart
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';

//colors.dart
const myGradient = LinearGradient(
  colors: [
    Color.fromRGBO(125, 158, 205, 1.0),
    Color.fromRGBO(115, 131, 163, 0.7490196078431373),
  ],
  begin: Alignment.centerLeft,
  end: Alignment.centerRight,
);


import 'colors.dart';

// page1.dart
class Page1 extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(gradient: myGradient),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you please provide a code example kindly

Comment: yes of course !!

Comment: List colorone = [
    gradient: myGradient,
    textblue,
    textWhite.withOpacity(0.3),
    listviewone.withOpacity(0.8),
    // listviewone,
  ]; <<< when I try to use this here. I'm getting this error >>> type 'LinearGradient' is not a subtype of type 'Color?'

Comment: sorry for the delay, you can use gradient only in places that accept the property of the Gradient type and derivatives, but not as color, in the case of the list that passed you can remove the `gradient:` which will be accepted